# Boot fails: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/

Tags: boot, grub2, timeout

I have a dedicated server with Hetzner running Ubuntu 22.04 (Kernel 5.15.0-27). They've added a new disk to my server, and since then I haven't been able to boot it.

Using the rescue system and checking the logs, I found out it's possibly failing because it's timing out trying to find the boot partition:

```
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3198101c\x2dc38b\x2d44f2\x2d865f\x2d9040cb8d2d01.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3198101c\x2dc38b\x2d44f2\x2d865f\x2d9040cb8d2d01.device/start timed out.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01.
```

Things I've tried with no success:

- Using UUIDs
- Using device names instead of UUIDs
- Using PARTUUID

For some reason it's not able to find the partitions ?

---

**/etc/fstab**

```
UUID=35088487-7aa5-45fd-8bef-94d15810aff0 swap swap sw 0 0
UUID=3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
UUID=4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482 / ext4 defaults 0 0
```

**blkid**

```
/dev/loop0: UUID="2dceb8c1-0bfe-488e-820a-e4f78326dc0a" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext2"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="5ab47f59-59d7-43fe-b803-37e0ab474364" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="803f299d-5e70-0040-8ee4-727341bb32bc"
/dev/sda4: UUID="f4ed4504-6406-4508-b03c-d351db6fb977" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="191b6f13-284f-4948-a230-973c0b8dc671"
/dev/sda2: UUID="3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01" SEC_TYPE="ext2" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="16fbc132-f1bb-40e5-bdba-b43d904502f2"
/dev/sda3: UUID="4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="71dc8199-8574-4dbb-8c57-17dae293ff6f"
/dev/sda1: UUID="35088487-7aa5-45fd-8bef-94d15810aff0" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="4aa21c01-785c-4065-830d-1d53197fc22c"
/dev/sdb: PTUUID="8d0e05f7-9171-4b35-9c6a-11f66a38310e" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sda5: PARTUUID="5ab858a9-567e-4ac8-8598-7de1b203945b"
```

**grub.cfg**

```
# grub-new
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="gnulinux-5.15.0-27-generic-advanced-4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

terminal_input console
terminal_output console
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
set linux_gfx_mode=text
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482' {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd2,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd2,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,gpt2  3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01
    fi
    linux   /vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482 ro consoleblank=0 systemd.show_status=true consoleblank=0
    initrd  /initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-39-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-39-generic-advanced-4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482' {
        recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd2,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd2,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,gpt2  3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-39-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482 ro consoleblank=0 systemd.show_status=true consoleblank=0
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-39-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-39-generic-recovery-4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482' {
        recordfail
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd2,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd2,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,gpt2  3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-39-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482 ro single nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr consoleblank=0 systemd.show_status=true
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-27-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-27-generic-advanced-4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482' {
        recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd2,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd2,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,gpt2  3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-27-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-5.15.0-27-generic root=UUID=4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482 ro consoleblank=0 systemd.show_status=true consoleblank=0
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-5.15.0-27-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-27-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-27-generic-recovery-4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482' {
        recordfail
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd2,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd2,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,gpt2  3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-27-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-5.15.0-27-generic root=UUID=4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482 ro single nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr consoleblank=0 systemd.show_status=true
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-5.15.0-27-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###
### END /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

**journalctl** (full log [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/d3vr/480bca06f6db19b655632d92c7ae56c1/raw/7b647e27cd90148cb56bf0458dc80f78978ddb91/journalctl))

```
Jul 10 18:37:53 beaver kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xea, date = 2021-01-05
Jul 10 18:37:53 beaver kernel: Linux version 5.15.0-39-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-069) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #42-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 9 23:42:32 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-39.42-generic 5.15.35)
Jul 10 18:37:53 beaver kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=4868b673-337c-4483-8e4e-c1d790776482 ro consoleblank=0 systemd.show_status=true consoleblank=0
Jul 10 18:37:53 beaver kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Jul 10 18:37:53 beaver kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Jul 10 18:37:53 beaver kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jul 10 18:37:53 beaver kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jul 10 18:37:53 beaver kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jul 10 18:37:53 beaver kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
[...]
Jul 10 18:37:53 beaver systemd[1]: modprobe@mtdpstore.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 18:37:53 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module mtdpstore.
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver kernel: EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd-journald[240]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/86be89edf56b43c58021f307b07c5987 is 148.139ms for 868 entries.
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd-journald[240]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/86be89edf56b43c58021f307b07c5987) is 1008.0M, max 4.0G, 3.0G free.
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Complete being skipped.
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jul 10 18:37:54 beaver systemd[1]: Reached target Preparation for Local File Systems.
Jul 10 18:37:55 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3198101c\x2dc38b\x2d44f2\x2d865f\x2d9040cb8d2d01.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3198101c\x2dc38b\x2d44f2\x2d865f\x2d9040cb8d2d01.device/start timed out.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/3198101c-c38b-44f2-865f-9040cb8d2d01.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /boot.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Job unattended-upgrades.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: boot.mount: Job boot.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3198101c\x2dc38b\x2d44f2\x2d865f\x2d9040cb8d2d01.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3198101c\x2dc38b\x2d44f2\x2d865f\x2d9040cb8d2d01.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-35088487\x2d7aa5\x2d45fd\x2d8bef\x2d94d15810aff0.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-35088487\x2d7aa5\x2d45fd\x2d8bef\x2d94d15810aff0.device/start timed out.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/35088487-7aa5-45fd-8bef-94d15810aff0.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/35088487-7aa5-45fd-8bef-94d15810aff0.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Swaps.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: swap.target: Job swap.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-35088487\x2d7aa5\x2d45fd\x2d8bef\x2d94d15810aff0.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-35088487\x2d7aa5\x2d45fd\x2d8bef\x2d94d15810aff0.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-35088487\x2d7aa5\x2d45fd\x2d8bef\x2d94d15810aff0.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-35088487\x2d7aa5\x2d45fd\x2d8bef\x2d94d15810aff0.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: systemd-ask-password-wall.path: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Stopped Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Reached target Timer Units.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Enable support for additional executable binary formats...
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Set console font and keymap...
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Create final runtime dir for shutdown pivot root...
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: syslog.socket: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Closed Syslog Socket.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Store a System Token in an EFI Variable being skipped.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Commit a transient machine-id on disk being skipped.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Set console scheme...
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Reached target Path Units.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Reached target Socket Units.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Load AppArmor profiles...
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Started Emergency Shell.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Reached target Emergency Mode.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Set console font and keymap.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 283 (update-binfmts)
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Create final runtime dir for shutdown pivot root.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Set console scheme.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Created slice Slice /system/getty.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Reached target Preparation for Network.
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Network Configuration...
Jul 10 18:39:23 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Enable support for additional executable binary formats.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver apparmor.systemd[287]: Restarting AppArmor
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver apparmor.systemd[287]: Reloading AppArmor profiles
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver dbus-daemon[288]: dbus[288]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd-networkd[297]: lo: Link UP
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd-networkd[297]: lo: Gained carrier
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd-networkd[297]: Enumeration completed
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Started Network Configuration.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver apparmor.systemd[312]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP...
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Wait for Network to be Configured.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver dbus-daemon[288]: [system] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[305]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=305 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[305]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=305 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1657471164.290:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=305 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1657471164.290:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=305 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[304]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=304 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1657471164.294:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=304 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[309]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=309 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[309]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=309 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[309]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=309 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Starting Record Runlevel Change in UTMP...
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1657471164.298:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=309 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1657471164.298:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=309 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1657471164.298:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=309 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd-update-utmp[318]: Failed to get new runlevel, utmp update skipped.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Record Runlevel Change in UTMP.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[311]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="i2pd" pid=311 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1657471164.326:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="i2pd" pid=311 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[310]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="tcpdump" pid=310 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[306]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=306 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[306]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=306 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[306]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=306 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[306]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/{,usr/}sbin/dhclient" pid=306 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[308]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/i2prouter" pid=308 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[308]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/i2prouter//sanitized_helper" pid=308 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[307]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="system_i2p" pid=307 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver audit[307]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="system_i2p//sanitized_helper" pid=307 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Finished Load AppArmor profiles.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Authentication service for virtual machines hosted on VMware being skipped.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Service for virtual machines hosted on VMware being skipped.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1657471164.346:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="tcpdump" pid=310 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1657471164.346:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=306 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1657471164.346:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=306 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd-resolved[314]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd-resolved[314]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd-resolved[314]: Negative trust anchors: home.arpa 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.arpa 21.172.in-addr.arpa 22.172.in-addr.arpa 23.172.in-addr.arpa 24.172.in-addr.arpa 25.172.in-addr.arpa 26.172.in-addr.arpa 27.172.in-addr.arpa 28.172.in-addr.arpa 29.172.in-addr.arpa 30.172.in-addr.arpa 31.172.in-addr.arpa 168.192.in-addr.arpa d.f.ip6.arpa corp home internal intranet lan local private test
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd-resolved[314]: Using system hostname 'beaver'.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[1]: Startup finished in 2.207s (kernel) + 1min 32.286s (userspace) = 1min 34.493s.
Jul 10 18:39:24 beaver systemd[289]: emergency.service: Executable /bin/plymouth missing, skipping: No such file or directory
```

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? - I'm seeing the exact same thing in Ubuntu 22.04 under vmware. Commenting the /boot entry in fstab allows it to boot but then there seems to be an issue with the network stack.

Comment: @Jona ended up just reinstalling the OS. I couldn't find a solution nor an explanation as to what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in mounted volumes in Hetzner & it's snapshot mechanic. You need to modify `/etc/fstab` and delete mounted volumes because you don't have them

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I was so frustrated and couldn't figure out a solution, I ended up just reinstalled the OS. Hopefully someone else (or future me) will find your answer useful!